# When will the webbrowsers have TLS 1.2 support?

Tags: tls

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_1.2_.28SSL_3.3.29

and

http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/09/19/beast_exploits_paypal_ssl/

when will the webbrowsers have TLS 1.2 support??

BEAST was in 2011 September!!

Comment: http://thehackernews.com/2012/01/next-microsoft-patch-tuesday-include.html

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32817/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lance - this is not really an on-topic question for here, as it comes down to "whenever the browser developers implement it" so this may get closed by the community.

In saying that, a quick google shows that some already have it enabled. the [ISC Diary had this in September](http://isc.sans.edu/diary.html?storyid=11629):

> The TLS support for browsers right now is:
>
> - IE9 TLS 1.0, 1.1, 1.2 all supported via Schannel
> - IE8 TLS 1.0 supported by default, 1.1 and 1.2 can be configured
> - Opera - 10.x supports TLS 1.0, 1.1, 1.2
>
> I don't count older versions of any of these browsers, since people really
> should have auto-update on. if they don't they've probably got bigger
> problems ( http://isc.sans.edu/diary.html?storyid=11527 )
>
> - Mozilla/Firefox - TLS 1.0 only
> - Chrome - TLS 1.0 only (though an update is rumoured)
> - Safari - TLS 1.0
> - Cell phones - various support levels (webkit has tls 1.2 since Nov 2010, but for
>   individual phone browser implementations your mileage may vary)