# Disable DES-CBC-SHA in schannel

Tags: tls, windows

I have several IIS servers in house This includes IIS 6 and 7.x. When I have my external PCI scans run I'm still receiving alerts for having the weak protocol DES-CBC-SHA enabled.

I have the following registry keys set to disable weak protocols. My understanding was that shutting this protocol off this was included under the DES entry on the top line.

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL
Ciphers/DES 56/56:  Enabled=0
Ciphers/RC2 40/128: Enabled=0
Ciphers/RC4 40/128: Enabled=0
Protocols/SSL 2.0/Server: Enabled=0
Protocols/PCT 1.0/Server: Enabled=0
```

My report indicates that this protocol is enabled for both TLSv1 and SSLv3.

What if anything am I missing in my settings that would make this display? How can I diagnose this internally to verify the scan is accurate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming IIS 7.x the settings you're looking for are located here:
Start > gpedit.msc > Computer Configuration > Admin Templates > Network > SSL Configuration Settings > SSL Cipher Suite Order

To set the order in such a way as to eliminate your issues, check my answer here:
[How to fix SSL 2.0 and BEAST on IIS](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14326/how-to-fix-ssl-2-0-and-beast-on-iis/19035#19035)

Also, though I doubt it's as comprehensive as your PCI compliance scans, you can check your setup at [Qualys SSL Labs Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) as an indicator of how you're progressing with the fix.

Unfortunately these settings are baked in for IIS 6.0 with no solution available.

Comment: This is applicable to IIS7,  not IIS6